Dynamic array formula to summary weekly data (like a pivot table)
I have been wrestling with ChatGPT (and losing) trying to find an answer to this one.
This is a sample of weekly data displayed in A2:D43021 of Sheet1.



DATE
ARTIST
SONG
THIS WEEK




1/3/1970
Diana Ross & The Supremes
Someday We'll Be Together
1


1/3/1970
Jackson 5
I Want You Back
2


1/3/1970
James Brown
Ain't It Funky Now (Part 1)
3


1/3/1970
Jr. Walker & The All Stars
These Eyes
4


1/3/1970
Gladys Knight And The Pips
Friendship Train
5


1/3/1970
Marvin Gaye & Tammi Terrell
What You Gave Me
6


1/3/1970
Johnnie Taylor
Love Bones
7


1/10/1970
Jackson 5
I Want You Back
1


1/10/1970
Diana Ross & The Supremes
Someday We'll Be Together
2


1/10/1970
James Brown
Ain't It Funky Now (Part 1)
3


1/10/1970
Jr. Walker & The All Stars
These Eyes
4


1/10/1970
Johnnie Taylor
Love Bones
5


1/10/1970
Marvin Gaye & Tammi Terrell
What You Gave Me
6


1/10/1970
Gladys Knight And The Pips
Friendship Train
7



Sheet2 currently looks like this.



1ST DATE
1ST POS
ARTIST
SONG
01/03/70
01/10/70






Diana Ross & The Supremes
Someday We'll Be Together






Jackson 5
I Want You Back






James Brown
Ain't It Funky Now (Part 1)






Jr. Walker & The All Stars
These Eyes






Gladys Knight And The Pips
Friendship Train






Marvin Gaye & Tammi Terrell
What You Gave Me






Johnnie Taylor
Love Bones





I'm looking for a single dynamic array formula for Sheet2 cell E2 (the cell under the date 01/03/70).
This formula should take the artist and song values in that row and date value in that column, find the row on Sheet1 with those values, and return the corresponding THIS WEEK value.
It should then spill those returned values down all rows and across all columns starting at Sheet2 cell E2.
Based on above example of Sheet1, Sheet2 should end up looking like this.



1ST DATE
1ST POS
ARTIST
SONG
01/03/70
01/10/70






Diana Ross & The Supremes
Someday We'll Be Together
1
2




Jackson 5
I Want You Back
2
1




James Brown
Ain't It Funky Now (Part 1)
3
3




Jr. Walker & The All Stars
These Eyes
4
4




Gladys Knight And The Pips
Friendship Train
5
7




Marvin Gaye & Tammi Terrell
What You Gave Me
6
6




Johnnie Taylor
Love Bones
7
5



I have used Power Query to create a pivot table but I would like to do more calculations directly from Sheet1.
My pc is too underpowered to handle lookup formulas in each cell.
I've worked with versions of this formula for cell E2 but I can't get a grip on the logic for populating both vertically and horizontally.
=LET(
    data,'Sheet1'!A2:D43021,
    artist, $C$2:$C$4557,
    song, $D$2:$D$4557,
    datehdr, $E$1:$TF$1,
    BYROW(artist&song,
        LAMBDA(row,
            MATCH(
                TRUE,
                (row=INDEX(data,,2)&INDEX(data,,3))*(INDEX(datehdr,,1)=INDEX(data,,1)),
                0
            )
        )
    )
)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I apologize for causing everyone to work way harder than they should. I have modified my question to better explain things (hopefully).

Oh GB, you needed only the last two columns? LOL!

Exactly! After I saw everyone trying to populate all of the columns, I knew more visuals were needed.

please try now i have updated in answers as well as in the link!

Try using the following formula, using LAMBDA() helper function MAKEARRAY() the following will generate the whole array as is mentioned in your OP:


• Formula used in cell C1 of Sheet2
=LET(
     _Data, Sheet1!A2:D15,
     _ArtistSong, CHOOSECOLS(_Data,2,3),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_ArtistSong),
     _Date, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Output, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Uniq),COLUMNS(DROP(C1:F1,,2)), LAMBDA(r,c,
     TOROW(FILTER(TAKE(_Data,,-1), (INDEX(_Uniq,r,1)=INDEX(_ArtistSong,,1))*
     (INDEX(_Uniq,r,2)=INDEX(_ArtistSong,,2))*(INDEX(DROP(C1:F1,,2),c)=_Date),"")))),
     HSTACK(_Uniq, _Output))


As per new update by OP:
=LET(
     α, C2:D8,
     δ, E1:F1,
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(α),COLUMNS(δ),LAMBDA(r,c,
     FILTER(Sheet1!D2:D15,(INDEX(α,r,1)=Sheet1!B2:B15)*
     (INDEX(α,r,2)=Sheet1!C2:C15)*(INDEX(δ,c)=Sheet1!A2:A15),""))))



Thank you for the single-formula solution.
When I place the formula anywhere in Sheet2 range A1:D43021, it causes a circular reference error.
On Sheet2, if I already have the header set up in row 1, how can the formula be edited to return the data only when placed in Sheet2 C2?

@GBMedusa well you will need to remove the headers. Let me update the same!

@GBMedusa just remove this part which is at the end: VSTACK(HSTACK(Sheet1!B1:C1,_UniqD), and one of the last brackets.

Remove all of the headers or just the ones in C1:F1?

@GBMedusa see i have updated, just copy that

The formula is still creating a circular reference.

@GBMedusa you can download the excel from here it shouldnt return an error

@GBMedusa also try the one which i have updated now! The one which I have updated now, it needs the headers as you have already.

Thanks for your help. I replaced the header and placed your formula in cell C2. Unfortunately, still getting the circ ref error. Also, unable to access the OneDrive file.
I will check back later after work.

@GBMedusa but you shouldn't get the error. No you keep your header which you have written manually. ok, and enter the formula in C2, the formula now uses the header, instead of embedding within the formula the TOROW(UNIQUE()) from the actual source.

Summarize Weekly Top List

You could use the following e.g. in Sheet2!A1:

=LET(data,Sheet1!A2:D43021,dcol,1,acol,2,scol,3,rcol,4,
        headers,{"1ST DATE";"1ST POS";"ARTIST";"SONG"},
    di,IF(data="","",data),d,FILTER(di,CHOOSECOLS(di,dcol)<>""),
    sd,CHOOSECOLS(d,dcol),sa,CHOOSECOLS(d,acol),
    ss,CHOOSECOLS(d,scol),sr,CHOOSECOLS(d,rcol),
    artist_song,UNIQUE(HSTACK(sa,ss)),
    au,TAKE(artist_song,,1),su,DROP(artist_song,,1),
    du,TOROW(UNIQUE(sd)),
    h,HSTACK(TOROW(headers),du),
    f_date,MAP(au,su,LAMBDA(a,s,XLOOKUP(1,(sa=a)*(ss=s),sd))),
    f_pos,MAP(au,su,LAMBDA(a,s,XLOOKUP(1,(sa=a)*(ss=s)*(sr=1),sd,""))),
    f_pos_count,MAP(au,su,LAMBDA(a,s,
        IFERROR(ROWS(FILTER(sd,(sa=a)*(ss=s)*(sr=1))),))),
    ranks,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(artist_song),COLUMNS(du),LAMBDA(r,c,
        XLOOKUP(1,(sd=INDEX(du,c))*(sa=INDEX(au,r))*(ss=INDEX(su,r)),sr,""))),
    r,VSTACK(h,HSTACK(f_date,f_pos,HSTACK(artist_song,ranks))),
    r)


Replace the bottom-most r with any other variable to see what it holds.
Using MAKEARRAY is probably the most efficient way to solve your problem i.e. focus on ranks.

Source

Result


Heavy Solution.

It s really not that heavy if dates are dynamic. I use reduce instead of makearray simply because it is easier to write. So used to intelisense that I just cannot get used to writing complicated formulas completely off hand on my own.

@rachel with Heavy i mean to say nice solution. Not the weight. In my mother tongue Heavy means that actually hebby , nice.

Another really lazy solution that I would advise you to use with caution:
=CHOOSECOLS(WRAPROWS(TOROW(SORT(A2:D15,{2,3},1,FALSE)),8),{2,3,4,8})

First, sort the data by song and artist name, so that row1 is 1/3/1970, row2 is 1/10/1970...

Then use WRAPROWS and TOROW to reshape the table:

Finally, use CHOOSECOLS to keep the relevant columns.
Edited:
Since this formula relies on the assumption that each (artist + song) has two rows, one for 1/3/1970, another for 1/10/1970, if that is not true, e.g if one of (artist + song) has three dates, or one only one date, this whole formula will breakdown.
And I saw other answers handle this properly, so I decided to the take some time to write a formula to handle this too.
That is, if one of the artist has three dates, it will still work:
=LET(
    data, A2:D16,
    sorted_dates, SORT(UNIQUE(INDEX(data, , 1), FALSE, FALSE), 1, 1),
    artists, INDEX(data, , 2),
    songs, INDEX(data, , 3),
    unique_artists_and_songs, UNIQUE(HSTACK(artists, songs), FALSE, FALSE),
    rowNum, ROWS(unique_artists_and_songs),
    colNum, ROWS(sorted_dates),
    REDUCE(
        HSTACK("Artist", "Song", TOROW(sorted_dates)),
        SEQUENCE(rowNum, 1, 1, 1),
        LAMBDA(a, i,
            LET(
                artist, INDEX(unique_artists_and_songs, i, 1),
                song, INDEX(unique_artists_and_songs, i, 2),
                filtered, FILTER(data, (artists = artist) * (songs = song), ""),
                dates, INDEX(filtered, , 1),
                ranks, INDEX(filtered, , 4),
                sorted_ranks, MAP(sorted_dates, LAMBDA(d, XLOOKUP(d, dates, ranks, "", 0))),
                result, HSTACK(artist, song, TOROW(sorted_ranks)),
                VSTACK(a, result)
            )
        )
    )
)



Not tested. But nice. However have you checked for the Odd Even!

@MayukhBhattacharya, I think the main problem with TOROW + WRAPROWS is that it relies on the assumption that each (artist + song) has two rows, one for 1/3/1970, another for 1/10/1970, if that is not true, e.g if one of (artist + song) has three dates, or only one date, not only will this whole formula breakdown, but it would be rather difficult to eyeball the problem too.

Another option:
=LET(header, A1:D1,
     data,   A2:D15,
     date,TAKE(data,,1),     artist,INDEX(data,,2),     song,INDEX(data,,3),     notation,DROP(data,,3),     unq,UNIQUE(HSTACK(artist,song)),
     unqdate,TOROW(UNIQUE(date)),     unqartist,TAKE(unq,,1),     unqsong,DROP(unq,,1),
VSTACK(HSTACK("1ST "&{"DATE","POS"},
              CHOOSECOLS(header,2,3),
              unqdate),
       HSTACK(XLOOKUP(unqartist&unqsong,artist&song,date),
              XLOOKUP(unqartist&unqsong&1,artist&song&notation,date,""),
              unq,
              WRAPCOLS(TOCOL(BYCOL(--REPT(notation,date&artist&song=TOROW(unqdate&unqartist&unqsong,,1)),LAMBDA(b,IFERROR(TOCOL(b,2),"")))),ROWS(unq),1))))

Where you change your header and data to your needs, the rest adapts to that ranges.
I tried using self explaining names inside LET.
Basically it looks up the first date of the artist & song combination,
next it looks up the first number 1 notation date, if applicable.
Then the unique artist/song combinations are stacked to that, followed by it's pivoted notations Using BYCOL/REPT.

Nice use case of BYCOL()
